# How to add a button in border?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton

I'm writing a program and I want to add button and label on top right above JTabbedPane. I use MatteBorder and I want to add label (not title) and 1 button where the blue border is. thanks for your help.

```
import java.awt.*;
import static java.awt.Font.BOLD;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import javax.swing.*;
import static javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;



public class hotels extends JFrame{

    JButton hotel;
    JLabel image;
     JTabbedPane tabbed,tabbed1;
    JPanel panel;
    JPanel panel1;

    Container pane;
    JPanel panel2;
    JLabel departure;
    JLabel from;
    JLabel to;


    public hotels(){


         panel=new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        hotel=new JButton();
        hotel.setText("Hotels");

        Font myFont = new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 18);


        hotel.setFont(myFont);
        panel.setLayout(null);
        panel.add(hotel);

        hotel.setBounds(50, 80, 100, 40);


        image=new JLabel();

        image.setBounds(50,1,80,80);
        image.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.yellow));
        image.setBackground(Color.white);
        image.setIcon(new ImageIcon("2.gif"));
        panel.add(image);

       panel1=new JPanel();
        panel1.setLayout(null);

      tabbed=new JTabbedPane();




         tabbed.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(24, 6, 12, 6, Color.blue));

          Font myFont1 = new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 18);
          tabbed.setFont(myFont1);

            tabbed.setBounds(0, 20, 80, 40);

     tabbed.add( "Round Trip",panel1);

     panel2=new JPanel();
     panel2.setLayout(null);
     panel2.setBackground(Color.white);
     departure=new JLabel();
     departure.setText("Departure");

     Font f=new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN,12);
     departure.setBounds(50,1,80,80);
     departure.setFont(f);
     panel2.add(departure);
       tabbed.add("One Way",panel2);
       from=new JLabel();
       from.setBackground(Color.blue);

       panel1.setBackground(Color.yellow);



        pane=getContentPane();


          pane.add(panel);

   image.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()

   {

      public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
           if (e.getSource()==image){

      pane.removeAll();

      pane.add(tabbed);
      pane.revalidate();
      pane.repaint();

           }


       }


   }


   );

    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {

 hotels mw=new hotels();
  mw.setVisible(true);
  mw.setSize(300, 400);


    }



    }
```

Comment: !) Format your code properly. 2) It is not clear what you want, either clear it up or post a picture of what you want to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to add button and label on top right above JTabbedPane.

You can add `Components` above the `JTabbedPane` by nesting `Container`s with the appropriate layout. For instance, to place a `JLabel` and `JButton` above and top right of the JTabbedPane, you can use a BoxLayout - in the `mouseClicked` implementation where the JTabbedPane is added:

```
pane.removeAll();
Box vert = Box.createVerticalBox();
Box top = Box.createHorizontalBox();
top.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
top.add(new JLabel("Top Label"));
top.add(new JButton("Top Button"));
vert.add(top);
vert.add(tabbed);
pane.add(vert);
....
```

Your requirements are not explicit, and so you may have to play with the background colors and border position (for instance, add the Border to `vert` rather than `tabbed`) to meet your requirements.

Comment: Thanks this is what I want. I would greatly appreciate if you solve my two issues.1st is there a way I can remove the box and just have "top button" and "top Label" itself. 2nd I want my "topbutton"  on top left corner and "toplabel" in the center.

Comment: The `Box` is there for it's LayoutManager - some type of Container (eg JPanel) must be there to layout the components. See the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29480695/center-jlabel-in-borderlayout-with-a-button-at-line-end) which provides a side positioned element with a centered element.

Comment: I add 2 new panels. But my tabs are above these 2 panels.I want both tabs below these 2 new panels. I try setBounds but nothing happens.

Comment: This is a different question than your original - consider marking this as solved (presuming it did so) and asking another question containing the necessary code that pertains to your new question